# How can I replace a literal \n with a newline character? (on OS X)

Tags: sed, osx, newlines

I have a script which pulls something out of my shell history and saves it to a file, but if there is a newline in the history entry it gets returned to me with a literal `\n` instead of the newline character.  I'd like to replace the `\n` with a newline before saving it to the file.

I'm on OS X, and figured the problem might be the BSD-based `sed` that ships with OS X (that always seems to be the problem when `sed` isn't behaving!)
 so I tried with `gsed`, and what was failing with `sed` worked on the first try with `gsed`:

```
history -1 | awk '{$1=""; print}' | gsed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e s/'\\n'/"\n"/
```

But if at all possible I'd like something that'll work with the default utilities (whether `sed` or something else) on both Linux or OS X, since I can't count on `gsed` being installed on OS X, and since GNU `sed` is the normal `sed` for Linux there is obviously no need for `gsed`.

Comment: To be sure I'm clear on this: you run this same 3-part pipeline using `sed`, and you get `\n`? Or do you mean that the `\n` is coming from `awk`?

Comment: I would guess it has nothing to do with `sed` or `gsed` ... it has to do with the shell you are using and the expansion of `"\n"`. Try the final `-e` option to sed as `-e 's/\\n/\n/g'` (the `g` will do all in the line rather than just the first, btw) (not confident this will work though).

Comment: @TomZych: it's really just the last `-e` expression that's failing.  The rest is just for context. Instead of a newline, I'm getting an `n` as the replacement with the code as shown if I use sed instead of gsed.  But I tried lots of different things and none of them worked except using gsed.

Comment: yeah - it is implementation defined how backslash escapes should be interpreted on the right-hand-side of a `s///`ubstitution. the portable way to do it is to backslash-escape a literal `\n`ewline character into the substitution.

Comment: Or, `awk` which you are using anyway portably (POSIXly) supports `\n` and friends on both pattern and substitute of `gsub` (and other places too). But note `$1=""` (with default FS) squashes whitespaces in the command; `sub(/^ [0-9]+  /,"")` works better on `bash history` and I expect something not very different should on `zsh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
sed 's/\\\\/& /g;s/\\n/\
/g;  s/\\\\ /\\\\/g' <in >out
```

...should handle the `\n`ewline replacements without misinterpreting backslash escapes - so you can still have a literal `\\n` in input. I'm a little fuzzy on how you can ever get a `\n` out of your history commands, though.

I tried w/ `zsh` to find out how a `\n`ewline might be read out from the history file without being escaped like that:

```sh
echo '
\n'
history -1
```

---

```
11355 echo '\n\n'
```

That won't do. So, I tried this instead:

```sh
hist(){ ! cat "$1"; }
echo '
\n'
FCEDIT=hist fc -1
```

---

```
echo '
\n'
```

...so that's probably what you should be doing instead

For some reason `zsh` escapes `\n`ewlines in `history` or `fc -l` output in an ambiguous way, but when it hands a history command over to some editor, it gives it the real thing.

`zsh`'s primary means of `history` manipulation is `fc`, and the `history` command is not much more than an alias for `fc -l`. When `fc` is called with the `-l` option it will list the matching history lines to stdout *(after ambiguously escaping any non-printable characters)*, but `fc`'s default behavior is to invoke another utility with one or more temp file arguments into which it has written all history matches for its args.

`fc` derives the name of the utility it invokes from the `$FCEDIT` environment variable, or, if it is unset or null, from `$EDITOR`, or, if likewise unsuccessful, defaults to `vi`. If the invoked utility returns true, `fc` will afterward attempt to run any commands it finds in the *(presumably)* edited temp files before removing them.

And so the above command sequence substitutes `cat` for any editor command, and inverts its return so that a successful readout of `fc`'s tempfiles will return false - to keep `fc` from trying to run the commands again.

A more complete, sort-of drop-in solution which doesn't need to call out to an external utility could look like:

```sh
history()
        case    $1      in
        (*/*) ! while   [ -r "$1" ]
                do      while   read -rE RTN
                        do :;   done    <$1
                shift;  done;;
        (*)     local   RTN=1  IFS=
                FCEDIT=history fc "$@"
                return  $((RTN*$?))
        esac
```

...which ought to handle almost transparently any argument list you might expect `zsh`'s `history` command to do; except that its output is always literal and it never includes history timestamps or event numbers in the output *(unless you call it like `history -l [args]`, in which case it will behave as the builtin `history`)*.

Comment: I'm on `zsh`, so maybe it's the `zsh` history command that does that.

Comment: @iconoclast - yeah, that doesn't work. i tried w/ a literal newline followed by a literal backslash then n in a `zsh` shell and it came out `echo '\n\n'`. there's no way to tell them apart. there's gotta be a way. seems silly like that.

Comment: @iconoclast - please see the edit.

Comment: cool.... I don't entirely understand your new solution, but I'll try to pick it apart to understand it...

Comment: @iconoclast - `fc -l` is what `history` aliases to. by default `fc` doesn't just print history commands, it hands them to some editor in a temporary file. the editor is `$FCEDIT`, or, if it is null or unset, `$EDITOR`, or, if it is null or unset, `vi`. when you pop into the editor to edit your command if the editor returns 0 when you're through then the newly edited command is newly executed all over again. that's why we `cat` our first argument - *(the shell's temporary file with our last history command)* - and `!` invert its return - so it doesn't return 0 and get reexecuted.

Comment: @iconoclast - i fleshed it out  a little more, in case you're interested.